# ios switch rootviewcontroller leading to crash which is caused by UIViewController over release

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I setup my scene in storyboard as follow, and set it as window.rootViewController:

> It's a tabbar controller, each tab view controller is embeded in navigation controller

[image]

Everything works fine, but when I add a switch button in order to set the window's rootviewcontroller to anther storyboard, the problems comes.

When I set the window.rootViewController to anther storyboard, the original rootViewController (the UITabbarController) gets dealloc.  This is what I expect, but the second tab view controller gets release twice, and lead to crash.

I use zombine instrument to analyze the reference count change as follow, almost all ref count is handled by UIKIt Library, I cannot figure out where goes wrong by me, is there any hint?

> BDBookingViewController is the controller of second tab, and the following is the reference counting of it

[image]

Here is the call stack of the last line in above picture

[image]

More call stack:
[image]
[image]

By the way, when I delete the dealloc function in BDBookingViewController, everything works fine. I just remove kvo there, I don't know the root reason

```
 - (void) dealloc
 {
    if ([self observationInfo]) {
        [[LoginManager sharedManager] removeObserver:self   forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(isLogin))    context:BDBookingViewControllerContext];                               
   }
  }
```